# How to say limit of this expression is finite

Tags: limits

I have to show that

$(1-\frac{t^2}{2r}+O(r^{-\frac{3}{2}}))^{-r}\rightarrow e^{\frac{t^2}{2}}$ as $r\rightarrow\infty$

I have expanded the given expression like below:

$(1-\frac{t^2}{2r}+O(r^{-\frac{3}{2}}))^{-r}$

$= (1-\frac{t^2}{2r})^{-r} - rO(r^{-\frac{3}{2}})(1-\frac{t^2}{2r})^{-r-1} + \binom{r+1}{2}(O(r^{-\frac{3}{2}}))^2(1-\frac{t^2}{2r})^{-r-2}-...$

As $r\rightarrow\infty$,

$(1-\frac{t^2}{2r})^{-r}\rightarrow e^{\frac{t^2}{2}}$

$rO(r^{-\frac{3}{2}})\rightarrow 0$, $\binom{r+1}{2}(O(r^{-\frac{3}{2}}))^2\rightarrow 0$ etc.

But **what about the terms $(1-\frac{t^2}{2r})^k, k=-r-1, -r-2,....$**

How can I say that they tend to a finite value? Can I say they are finite because $(1-\frac{t^2}{2r})^{-r}$ tends to a finite value(i.e. $e^{\frac{t^2}{2}}$)?

Comment: Do you know the limit $(1+ \frac1n)^n \to e$?

Comment: @md2perpe Yes. Like here I have written that $(1-\frac{t^2}{2r})^{-r} \to e^{\frac{t^2}{2}}$. What I want to know is whether $(1-\frac{t^2}{2r})^{k} \to$ a finite value($k=-r-1, -r-2$ and so on). I guess these terms do tend to a finite value, but I want someone to clarify the logic behind it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Taylor Theorem, it is easy to show that $\log(1-x)=-x+O(x^2)$, from which we have

$$\begin{align}
\left(1-\frac{t^2}{2r}+O\left(r^{-3/2}\right)\right)^{-r}&=e^{-r\log\left(1-\frac{t^2}{2r}+O\left(r^{-3/2}\right)\right)}\\\\
&=e^{t^2/2}e^{-O(r^{-1/2})}
\end{align}$$

Therefore, we see that

$$\lim_{r\to \infty }\left(1-\frac{t^2}{2r}+O\left(r^{-3/2}\right)\right)^{-r}=e^{t^2/2}$$

as was to be shown!

---

---

**EDIT:**

The OP was interested in proceeding with a binomial expansion.  To that end, we now use a generalized binomial expansion of the term if interest to write

$$\begin{align}
\left(1-\frac{t^2}{2r}+O\left(r^{-3/2}\right)\right)^{-r}&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{-r}{k}\left(1-\frac{t^2}{2r}\right)^{-r-k}O\left(r^{-3/2}\right)^k\tag1
\end{align}$$

where the generalized binomial coefficient, $\binom{-r}{k}$, is given by

$$\binom{-r}{k}=\frac{-r(-r-1)\cdots (-r-k+1)}{k!}$$

Owing to the uniform convergence of the series on the right-hand side of $(1)$, we can interchange the order of the limit and the summation to obtain

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{r\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{-r}{k}\left(1-\frac{t^2}{2r}\right)^{-r-k}O\left(r^{-3/2}\right)^k&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \lim_{r\to \infty}\left(\binom{-r}{k}\left(1-\frac{t^2}{2r}\right)^{-r-k}O\left(r^{-3/2}\right)^k\right)\\\\
&=e^{t^2/2}
\end{align}$$

since for $k\ne 0$,

$$\binom{-r}{k}O\left(r^{-3/2}\right)^k=O\left(r^{-1/2}\right)^k\to 0$$

as $r\to \infty$ and

$$\lim_{r\to \infty}\left(1-\frac{t^2}{2r}\right)^{-r-k}=e^{t^2/2}$$

Comment: I guess in the last line it will be $e^{t^2}$, not $e^{-t^2}$. And sorry to say, but I cannot get how this answer addresses my issue. What I want to know is whether $(1-\frac{t^2}{2r})^{k} \to$ a finite value($k=-r-1, -r-2$ and so on). I guess these terms do tend to a finite value, but I want someone to clarify the logic behind it.

Comment: Thank you for catching the typo.  I've edited accordingly.  As for your expansion, it seems to have a flaw.

Comment: @user587389 I've added a new section that addresses your specific question.

Comment: @user587389 Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Comment: Can you tell me how I can prove the last line of your answer, i.e., $\lim_{r\rightarrow\infty}(1-\frac{t^2}{2r})^{-r-k}=e^{kt^2/2}$? That was my question actually. However, thank you for your effort and sorry for my late reply.

Comment: First, you're certainly welcome.  It's my pleasure to help.  One if the several characterizations of the exponential function is  $$e^x\equiv \lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n$$Now let $x=-t^2/2$.

Comment: Oh.  There was a typo.  There is no $k$ in the exponent.

Comment: I know that $\lim_{r\rightarrow\infty}(1-\frac{t^2}{2r})^{-r}=e^{\frac{t^2}{2}}$. I want to know if $\\lim_{r\rightarrow\infty}(1-\frac{t^2}{2r})^{-r-k}$ will be finite and how?$(k=1,2,...)$

Comment: For each fixed $k$, $\lim_{r\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{t^2}{2r}\right)^{-k}=1$.  The uniform convergence property guarantees that we can interchange the limit with the infinite series.  Is that clearer?

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.